# Div Side By Side Background Color Not Filling Height

Tags: html, css-tables

I know a lot of topics have been written about div side by side, but I couldn't find a solution for my specific issue. I managed to get 2 divs side by side, and be mobile friendly (not require sideways scrolling), but there's a background color problem. If 1 div has little text while the div next to it doesn't, then the missing blocks of height just show blank instead of having a background. How can I fix this while staying mobile friendly?

Example page: http://www.gloryhood.com/articles/ztest.html

CSS:

```
div.table {
max-width: 100%;
}
div.firsthalf {
background-color: #ffffff;
float: left;
max-width: 50%;
text-align: left;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
div.secondhalf {
background-color: #ffffff;
margin-left: 50%;
max-width: 50%;
text-align: left;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="table">
<div class="firsthalf"> Leftcvniowdcnnvcidocniodsdckscksldncskdlcnklsdncklsdncskldcowdicnwcnowencweioncwiocniowecioweniowenciowenciowencweoicniowenoci 
</div>
<div class="secondhalf">
Righvidonvodsnvojsdnvjosdnvjosdnvjosdnbvjcmsdkcmnksdoncksdlcnsdlkcnsdjklncjklsdncjlksdcljksdcjksdosdnvjosdnvsodnvslodnvsdlonvt
</div>
<div class="firsthalf">
Leftcvni
</div>
<div class="secondhalf">
Righvidonvodsnvojsdnvjosdnvjosdnvjosdnbvjcmsdkcmnksdoncksdlcnsdlkcnsdjklncjklsdncjlksdcljksdcjksdosdnvjosdnvsodnvslodnvsdlonvt
</div>
<div class="firsthalf">
Leftcvniowdcnnvcidocniodsdckscksldncskdlcnklsdncklsdncskldcowdicnwcnowencweioncwiocniowecioweniowenciowenciowencweoicniowenoci
</div>
<div class="secondhalf">
Righvid
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am getting what exactly you want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.container').each(function(){
            var firstDiv = $(this).find('.firsthalf');
            var secondDiv = $(this).find('.secondhalf');
            if(firstDiv.height() >= secondDiv.height()){
                secondDiv.css('height',firstDiv.height());
            } else {
                firstDiv.css('height',secondDiv.height());
            }
        });
    });
```

```css
body{background: #39b1a4;}
    div.table {
    max-width: 100%;
}
div.firsthalf {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: left;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    
}
div.secondhalf {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: left;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    float: right;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="firsthalf"> Leftcvniowdcnnvcidocniodsdckscksldncskdlcnklsdncklsdncskldcowdicnwcnowencweioncwiocniowecioweniowenciowenciowencweoicniowenoci 
        </div>

        <div class="secondhalf">
        Righvidonvodsnvojsdnvjosdnvjosdnvjosdnbvjcmsdkcmnksdoncksdlcnsdlkcnsdjklncjklsdncjlksdcljksdcjksdosdnvjosdnvsodnvslodnvsdlonvt
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="firsthalf">
        Leftcvni
        </div>

        <div class="secondhalf">
        Righvidonvodsnvojsdnvjosdnvjosdnvjosdnbvjcmsdkcmnksdoncksdlcnsdlkcnsdjklncjklsdncjlksdcljksdcjksdosdnvjosdnvsodnvslodnvsdlonvt
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="firsthalf">
        Leftcvniowdcnnvcidocniodsdckscksldncskdlcnklsdncklsdncskldcowdicnwcnowencweioncwiocniowecioweniowenciowenciowencweoicniowenoci
        </div>

        <div class="secondhalf">
        Righvid
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Maddy, the Run code snippet works precisely how I wanted. However, I still can't get it to work on my site.

From the JS code:
I changed secondDiv.css to 1.css and firstDiv.css to 1.css as well, since that's my actual css file.

From the HTML code:
I changed <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> to <script src="1.js"></script> since that's where I put the JS code of yours.

Everything else I did precisely as you wrote. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: By the way, the reason I don't just opt for a table is because of its difficulty with break-word.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but I've tried everything I can think of and it's still not working (including adding that path to my script). I've made the code very minimalist and have put it together precisely how you've shown. I don't know where I might be still going wrong.
http://www.gloryhood.com/articles/ztest.html
http://www.gloryhood.com/articles/1.js
http://www.gloryhood.com/articles/2.css

Comment: There is no problem is your code just add this in your header:
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`
`<script type="text/javascript" src="1.js"></script>` not in body

Comment: Done! My apologies for not doing it earlier, I'm still pretty new to using this site and wasn't aware of that function.